# How to resolve the host / machine name with an IP address on windows phone

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-8, dns, windows-phone

Anyone know if it can recover the ( hostname/machine name ) with a local IP address ? I know that the resolution reverse 'hostname -> ip' works perfectly with `DeviceNetworkInformation.ResolveHostNameAsync (endpoint, OnNameResolved, null).`

Is it possible to do the same thing but in reverse? Given the IP of a Local Machine and retrieve its hostname? A thousand thanks

**Here is my code** , but it's doesn't work the host is always called **"192.168.1.5"** like the ip . And it's should return **"computer0001"**

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.ResolveHostNameAsync("192.168.1.5", OnNameResolved, null);

private void OnNameResolved(NameResolutionResult result)
{
     IPEndPoint[] endpoints = result.IPEndPoints;
     if (endpoints != null)
     {
         if (endpoints.Length > 0)
         {
             //Host always return ip adress and not the machine name
             host = endpoints[0].ToString();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you testing this code on emulator?

Comment: yes both of them , i already try on emulator and on a true device ( lumia 925)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is specific API on Windows Phone for that purpose.

I suggest you looking into [similar question 'DNS lookup from custom DNS server in c#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227863/dns-lookup-from-custom-dns-server-in-c-sharp).

If you're okay with going only WP8, then you should study this part of MSDN - [Supported Win32 APIs for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662956(v=vs.105).aspx).

For example, [getpeername function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms738533(v=vs.105).aspx) might return you information you're looking for. Or you might create new [HostName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/br207118.aspx) object passing IP address there and trying to read DisplayName, CanonicalName or RawName properties of it.

Make sure you test with both emulator and real device as WP8 emulator has a little bit complex network configuration.

Would be great if you can update us if you have any success with the task.

Comment: Thank you , yes my application target only WP8, so i will try this evening, if your solution work with the "getpeername function"

Comment: Sorry but are you sure [getpeername function] return me the host with a ip ? I don't think so .. It's only return 0 or 1 ->> If no error occurs, getpeername returns zero. Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling

Comment: int getpeername(
  _In_     SOCKET s,
  _Out_    struct sockaddr *name,
  _Inout_  int *namelen
);

Comment: No, I'm not sure, I'm just guessing and pointing you to look at Win32 API

Comment: Ok thanks as well, i will check if they have another win32 api function for do that , but getpeername function i'm sure only return a integer and not a hostname

Comment: as I mentioned before, it has a return value and in-out parameters. So I think it returns main information via those parameters, not via int. Int stands only for success/failure